# Vue.js/Vuetify 3 - Changing theme produces 'Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property' error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to toggle my vuetify 3 theme between light mode and dark using a button.

It seems the [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#api) sets the theme using `theme.global.name` but this does not work as it is a readonly property.

Is there a work around this?

Here's a snippet of my code below:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      theme: useTheme()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTheme() {
      this.theme.global.name = this.theme.global.current.dark ? 'light' : 'dark'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the error message produced: `Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)`

Comment: `useTheme` is a composable.  you can only use it with Composition API which the documentation code shows.  In Options API accessing the global Vuetify object is done with `this.$vuetify`, or for your case, `this.$vuetify.theme.global.name`